# adjust number of messages in posix message queue

Tags: c, linux, posix, message-queue

When i trying to reduce the number of message in POSIX message queue, its maintaining maximum of 10. Is it possible to reduce or increase the number of messages in POSIX message queue?

following code send the message to POSIX message queue. I set maximum message(MQ_MAX_NUM_OF_MESSAGES) to 5 but it sending 10 messages

send.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MSGQOBJ_NAME    "/myqueue123"
#define MAX_MSG_LEN     70
#define MQ_MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH 70
#define MQ_MAX_NUM_OF_MESSAGES 5
struct mq_attr attr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
mqd_t msgq_id;
unsigned int msgprio = 0;
pid_t my_pid = getpid();
char msgcontent[MAX_MSG_LEN];
int create_queue = 0;
char ch;            /* for getopt() */
time_t currtime;

attr.mq_flags = 0; 
attr.mq_maxmsg = MQ_MAX_NUM_OF_MESSAGES;
attr.mq_msgsize = MQ_MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH;
attr.mq_curmsgs = 0; 

while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "qp:")) != -1) {
    switch (ch) {
        case 'q':   /* create the queue */
            create_queue = 1;
            break;
        case 'p':   /* specify client id */
            msgprio = (unsigned int)strtol(optarg, (char **)NULL, 10);
            printf("I (%d) will use priority %d\n", my_pid, msgprio);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Usage: %s [-q] -p msg_prio\n", argv[0]);
            exit(1);
    }
}   
if (msgprio == 0) {
    printf("Usage: %s [-q] -p msg_prio\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}
if (create_queue) {
    msgq_id = mq_open(MSGQOBJ_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG, NULL);
} else {
    msgq_id = mq_open(MSGQOBJ_NAME, O_RDWR);
}
if (msgq_id == (mqd_t)-1) {
    perror("In mq_open()");
    exit(1);
}

currtime = time(NULL);
snprintf(msgcontent, MAX_MSG_LEN, "Hello from process %u (at %s).", my_pid, ctime(&currtime));  
mq_send(msgq_id, msgcontent, strlen(msgcontent)+1, msgprio);   
mq_close(msgq_id);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you are not passing the attribute structure to mq_open call.Pass it as last parameter, instead of NULL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview) for posix message queue, you can read how to tune the related kernel configuration via the **/proc** filesystem.

In particular **/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max** is what you are looking for:

> This file can be used to view and change the ceiling value for the maximum number of messages in a queue. This value acts as a **ceiling** on the attr->mq_maxmsg argument given to mq_open(3). The default value for msg_max is 10. The minimum value is 1 (10 in kernels before 2.6.28). The upper limit is **HARD_MAX**: (131072 / sizeof(void *)) (32768 on Linux/86). **This limit is ignored for privileged processes** (CAP_SYS_RESOURCE), but the HARD_MAX ceiling is nevertheless imposed.

**edit**
As explained in the [mq_open(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mq_open), [mq_getattr(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_getattr) and [mq_send(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_send) manual pages, the **mq_maxmsg** value sets the maximum number of message that the queue can handle without blocking (or returning **EAGAIN** in case of non-blocking queues). If you mq_open a queue with mq_maxmsg = 5 and the kernel configuration in **/proc** is 10 (the default, AFAIK) than the queue will accept 5 message without blocking. If you mq_open a queue with mq_maxmsg = 15 and the kernel configuration in **/proc** is 10, the queue will accept 10 message. That is: you can create a queue that hold a max number of message that is lower than the maximum number of messages that the kernel accepts, but not greater.

Comment: thanks. Then what is the use of mq_maxmsg in mq_attr structure.

Comment: Explained in the edit. BTW, linux manual pages are there for you... :-)