# IPCS message passing related queries

Tags: unix, operating-system, message-passing, ipcs

I am dealing with Message Passing IPCS method. I do have few question regarding this:

1. KEY field in `ipcs -q` shows me `0x00000000`  what does this means ?
2. Can i see what messsage is passes using msqid ?
3. If two entries are present (for a particular user) after executing command `ipcs -q`. Does this means that two messages were passed by this particular user ?
4. If used-bytes and message fields are set as 0 what does this mean?
5. Is there away to see if message queue is full or not?
6. How many queues can we have for one particular user?

I tried goggling, but was not able to find answer to these questions.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** The "**key**" field of the Shared memory segments is usually **`0x00000000`**. This indicates the **`IPC_PRIVATE`** key specified during creation of the shared memory segment. The [manual of shmget()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget) contains more details.

**2.** AFAIK, this cannot be done. If any msg is "de-queued" from the msgQ, then the intended receiver will not see it.

**3.** The 2 entries in the list of message queues indicates that there are currently 2 active message queues on the system identified by their corresponding unique keys.

Creating additional msgQ : `ipcmk -Q`
Deleting an existing msgQ : `ipcrm -Q <unique-key>`

**4.** The `used-bytes` and `messages` fields set to 0 indicate that currently no transfers have occurred using that particular msgQ.

**5.** Currently one way to do this to obtain the number of msgs currently queued-up in the msgQ programmatically as shown in the following C snippet. Next this can be compared with the size of the msgQ as demonstrated in this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15728442/319204)**.

```
int ret = msgctl(msqid, IPC_STAT, &buf);  
uint msg = (uint)(buf.msg_qnum);  
printf("msgs in Q = %u\n", msg);
```

**6.** There exists a limit on the total memory used by all the msgQs on the system combined together. This can be obtained by `ulimit -q`. The amount of bytes used in a msgQ is listed under the `used-bytes` column in the output of `ipcs -Q`. The total number of msgQs is limited only by the amount of memory available to create a new msgQ from the msgQ memory pool limit seen above.

Also checkout the latter part of this answer for a few sample operations on [POSIX message queues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6935).